# Div hide/show not working properly which using draggable and droppable - jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, hover, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

My issue is: while I drag the draggable content to the droppable area the corresponding `<li>` which contains the class `subtopic-drop-playlist` should open and it's happening and the `<ul class="topic-list">` becomes `display:block` and it's showing the below content.

What my problem is when I move the dragged content inside the `<ul class="topic-list">` the second `<li>` which contains the class `subtopic-drop-playlist` is opening..

It should not open..

The second `<li>` which contains the class `subtopic-drop-playlist` should open when I hover the cursor on that particular `<li>`.

Else it should not. I have given the code which is used below...

Any help will be thankful and grateful...

**Droppable Area**

```
<ul class="play-lists">
    <li class="subtopic-drop-playlist ui-droppable" id="nid_471">
        <h4 class="title-exp-coll title-collapse"><span class="exp-coll-playlist"></span><a href="/playlist/test">test</a></h4>
        <ul class="topic-list" style="display: none; ">
            <li class="subtopic-drop ui-droppable" topic_id="412326" nid="471"><h5>Topic 1</h5>
                <ul class="asset-list">
                    <li>
                        <div> <a href="/asset/sarav-asset-afternoon2">Sub Topic 1</a></div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div> <a href="/asset/sarav-asset-afternoon">Sub Topic 2</a></div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="first"></li>
    <li class="subtopic-drop-playlist ui-droppable" id="nid_469">
        <h4 class="title-exp-coll title-collapse"><span class="exp-coll-playlist"></span><a href="/playlist/sarava">Sarava</a></h4>
        <ul class="topic-list" style="display: none; ">
            <li class="subtopic-drop ui-droppable" topic_id="412324" nid="469"><h5>Topic 1</h5>
                <ul class="asset-list">
                    <li>
                        <div> <a>Sub Topic 1</a></div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div> <a>Sub Topic 2</a></div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Draggable Content:**

```
<div id="asset-block-content">
    <div class="clearfix comm-list-title">
        <h3>
            <div class="asset-links asset-image asset-draggable ui-draggable" content_asset="450" content_type="asset" class_type="asset-html" content_title="fdasfdasfsa"><a title="Click to view content" href="/asset/fdasfdasfsa">fdasfdasfsa</a>
            </div>
        </h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Show/Hide While Dragging the content to the Droppable area:**

```
function openclosePlaylist() {
    $(this).parent().next().toggle();
    if ($(this).parent().hasClass('active')) {
        $(this).parent().removeClass("title-expand active").addClass("title-collapse");
    }
    else {
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        $(this).parent().removeClass("title-collapse").addClass("title-expand active");
    }
}
```